# Rails Best Practices - Can I use a lot of "has many"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm a newbie creating my first app, and some ruby lovers told me that my ways of coding where not efficients. Because it's a lot of work to come to a clean state, I want to be sure to do what is better for me.

In the following code, do you think I'm overusing the `has_many` method, and if so, how should I replace it ?

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Offerers
  has_many :ownerships, dependent: :destroy 
  has_many :owners, through: :ownerships,
                      source: :offerer

  # Seekers
  has_many :loans, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :borrowers, through: :loans,
                     source: :seeker



  # Owners
  has_many :previous_ownerships, -> { where 'owning_date IS NOT NULL AND giving_date IS NOT NULL', agreed: true },
                                 class_name: 'Ownership'
  has_one :current_ownership, -> { where current: true, agreed: true },
                             class_name: 'Ownership'
  has_many :next_ownerships, -> { where owning_date: nil, giving_date: nil },
                             class_name: 'Ownership'

  has_many :previous_owners, through: :previous_ownerships,
                             source: :offerer
  has_one :owner, through: :current_ownership,
                  source: :offerer
  has_many :next_owners, through: :next_ownerships,
                         source: :offerer


  # Borrowers
  has_many :previous_loans, -> { where 'return_date IS NOT NULL AND borrowing_date IS NOT NULL', agreed: true },
                            class_name: 'Loan'
  has_one :current_loan, -> { where current: true, agreed: true },
                               class_name: 'Loan'
  has_many :next_loans, -> { where borrowing_date: nil, return_date: nil },
                                  class_name: 'Loan'

  has_many :previous_borrowers, through: :previous_loans,
                                source: :seeker
  has_many :next_borrowers, through: :next_loans,
                            source: :seeker
  has_one :borrower, through: :current_loan,
                              source: :seeker

 # Agreed or refused owners
  has_many :agreed_ownerships, -> { where agreed: true, owning_date: nil, giving_date: nil },
                                 class_name: 'Ownership'
  has_many :possible_ownerships, -> { where agreed: nil, owning_date: nil, giving_date: nil },
                                 class_name: 'Ownership'
  has_many :refused_ownerships, -> { where agreed: false, owning_date: nil, giving_date: nil },
                                 class_name: 'Ownership'
  has_many :agreed_owners, through: :agreed_ownerships,
                             source: :offerer
  has_many :possible_owners, through: :possible_ownerships,
                             source: :offerer
  has_many :refused_owners, through: :refused_ownerships,
                             source: :offerer

  # Agreed or refused borrowers
  has_many :agreed_loans, -> { where agreed: true, borrowing_date: nil, return_date: nil },
                                 class_name: 'Loan'
  has_many :possible_loans, -> { where agreed: nil, borrowing_date: nil, return_date: nil },
                                 class_name: 'Loan'
  has_many :refused_loans, -> { where agreed: false, borrowing_date: nil, return_date: nil },
                                 class_name: 'Loan'
  has_many :agreed_borrowers, through: :agreed_loans,
                             source: :seeker
  has_many :possible_borrowers, through: :possible_loans,
                             source: :seeker
  has_many :refused_borrowers, through: :refused_loans,
                             source: :seeker
```

Answer (score 1):

In many places you're using `has_many` as if it were a scope.

Read up on scopes [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes).

Scopes allow you to define a query that can then be accessed like a method. For example:

```
class Loan < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :current, where(current: true, agreed: true)
end
```

Can be called like so: `Product.first.loans.current`

Make sure you put these scopes in the appropriate models too, you don't want to filter your loans in the product model for instance.

Comment: Thanks ! How can I do if I want to get the associated users of my products ? Is `Product.first.loans.current.borrowers` going to work ?

Comment: It should do, so long as all your relationships and scopes are defined in a nice rails way. Give it a go!

Comment: No it doesn't work... `Product.first.loans.current` send back an array of `loans`, so I can not use a chained method that apply on one object only...

Comment: Scopes will always return a collection - you will need to do `.first` on the end of the chain to get one object, even if the collection is one item long.

Comment: I know, but how can I retrieve every previous borrowers of my product ? `Product.first.loans.past` and after ?